# Visual Studio 2015 tableadapeters visualizer shows green and blue colors

Tags: visual-studio-2015, dataset, tableadapter

My visual Studio 2015 tableadapeters visualizer shows green and blue colors for some, not all tableadapters. I can't even select the columns or queries that are defined within each tableadapter anymore. The code still works though.
How can I fix this? I tried restarting my PC, but it's always the same tableadapters that keep showing the colors.
See it here:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, turns out that when I click the double arrows down on each tableadapter, the fields show up again. Weird, but it did the trick.